Dynamically change order of nested loops containing business logic in Python
I'm developing a script for a lab instrumentation campaign. The instrument we're working with takes in various parameters such as x and y coordinates, power, delay, pulse, and so forth.
One crucial aspect of the operation involves 2d scanning an object, which requires iterating over both x and y coordinates. The sequence and amount of loops may change considering the variations in parameters.
My objective is to enhance the flexibility of the following pseudo-code, ideally reducing the level of nested loops if possible.
for x, y in zip(x_coords, y_coords):
  instr.move_axes(x, y)
  do_something_else_x_y()

  for power in params['power_list']:
    instr.set_power(power)
    do_something_else_power()

    for delay in params['delay_list']:
      instr.set_delay(delay)
      do_something_else_delay()

      for pulse in params['pulse_list']:
        instr.set_pulse(pulse)
        do_something_else_pulse()

I tried something with itertools.product() which flattens the nested for loops but I don't know how to insert the logic to communicate with the instrument without resorting to a lot of if conditions. It takes "long" time to communicate with the instrument so I want to set a value in the instrument only when there is a change.
The following code is easier to change the order of elements but seems to require more logic at the end to avoid calling the instrument unnecessary.
for (x, y), power, delay, pulse in product(zip(x_coords, y_coords), power_list, delay_list, pulse_list):
  print(x, y, power, delay, pulse)

  # implement additional logic to check if x, y, power, delay, pulse etc. changed so call the instrument.

  if difference_xy():
    instr.move_axes(x, y)
    do_something_else_x_y()

  if difference_power():
    instr.set_power(power)
    do_something_else_power()

  if difference_delay():
    instr.set_delay(delay)
    do_something_else_delay()

  if difference_pulse():
    instr.set_pulse(pulse)
    do_something_else_pulse()

  do_something_else()

Any ideas on this subject would be appreciated.

This is a perfect use case for functional programming... You may define functions and pass them around as values, so you can have a function to rearrange functions with each other. Any specific question (I'm not going to reimplement all that)?

Notably, by the BDFL, fp is considered generally unpythonic if you care about that

@TimothyH I think that mostly applied to using filter, map and reduce, not the more general principle you described

You're talking about the harmful reference? Far as that goes I'm aware he softened his stance but I did read some rants from him where he droned on about not getting "it", he did end up allowing the feature.

Granted now probably it is considered pythonic just because people have been using it so (shrug)

I think he is still pretty opposed to reduce, but AFAIK, his stance on map and filter is "just use a list/set/dict comprehension (or generator expression)", which are functional programming constructs (ripped from Haskell). I do agree that Python is fundamentally an imperative language, but it borrows from functional languages where it deems it useful, and using higher-order functions to organize your programs, I think, is perfectly in line with the spirit of the language (why else would you have first-class functions). But at the end of the day, it is an imperative, OOP language

Where does do_something_else() come from all of a sudden and for no apparent reason? And please fix the indentation.

Your second approach would only need a concise and generalized way to check for changes as you progress through the combinations.
You could write a changed function to track the last value of each parameter and detect if you need to adjust the instrument.  This would not add too much clutter to your code.
For example:
def changed(key,value):
    if key in changed.tracking and changed.tracking[key] == value:
        return False
    changed.tracking[key] = value
    return True
changed.tracking = {}

Usage:
from itertools import product

coordinates = [(1,2),(2,3),(4,5)]
powers = [10,20,30]
delays = [1,1.5,2]
pulses = [3,5,7]

changed.tracking.clear()
for (x,y),power,delay,pulse in product(coordinates,powers,delays,pulses):

    if changed("coord",(x,y)):
        # call your coordinate functions here
        print("setting coordinates to",(x,y))

    if changed("power",power):
        # call your power functions here
        print("setting power to",power)

    if changed("delay",delay):
        # call your delay functions here
        print("setting delay to",delay)

    if changed("pulse",pulse):
        # call your pulse functions here
        print("setting pulse to",pulse)

    # processing of current combination (now optimally setup on instrument)
    print("processing: ",(x,y),power,delay,pulse)
        

Output:
setting coordinates to (1, 2)
setting power to 10
setting delay to 1
setting pulse to 3
processing:  (1, 2) 10 1 3
setting pulse to 5
processing:  (1, 2) 10 1 5
setting pulse to 7
processing:  (1, 2) 10 1 7
setting delay to 1.5
setting pulse to 3
processing:  (1, 2) 10 1.5 3
setting pulse to 5
processing:  (1, 2) 10 1.5 5
setting pulse to 7
processing:  (1, 2) 10 1.5 7
setting delay to 2
setting pulse to 3
processing:  (1, 2) 10 2 3
setting pulse to 5
processing:  (1, 2) 10 2 5
...

If you also need to vary the nesting of parameters, you can use an indirection for the call to itertools.product() that you remap to  a fixed order of variables within the loop:
coordinates = [(1,2),(2,3),(4,5)]
powers      = [10,20,30]
delays      = [1,1.5,2]
pulses      = [3,5,7]
parameters  = {"C":coordinates, "P":powers, "D":delays, "I":pulses}

nesting     = "IDPC" # order in which you want to vary parameters

changed.tracking.clear()
*indexes,   = map("CPDI".index, nesting)
for values in product(*map(parameters.get, nesting)):
    
    # assign parameters in known (CPDI) order
    (x,y),power,delay,pulse = (values[i] for i in indexes)
    
    if changed("C",(x,y)):
        # call your coordinate functions here
        print("setting coordinates to",(x,y))

    if changed("P",power):
        # call your power functions here
        print("setting power to",power)

    if changed("D",delay):
        # call your delay functions here
        print("setting delay to",delay)

    if changed("I",pulse):
        # call your pulse functions here
        print("setting pulse to",pulse)

    # processing of current combination (now optimally setup on instrument)
    print("processing: ",(x,y),power,delay,pulse) 

output:
setting coordinates to (1, 2)
setting power to 10
setting delay to 1
setting pulse to 3
processing:  (1, 2) 10 1 3
setting coordinates to (2, 3)
processing:  (2, 3) 10 1 3
setting coordinates to (4, 5)
processing:  (4, 5) 10 1 3
setting coordinates to (1, 2)
setting power to 20
processing:  (1, 2) 20 1 3
setting coordinates to (2, 3)
processing:  (2, 3) 20 1 3
setting coordinates to (4, 5)
processing:  (4, 5) 20 1 3
setting coordinates to (1, 2)
setting power to 30
processing:  (1, 2) 30 1 3
setting coordinates to (2, 3)
processing:  (2, 3) 30 1 3
setting coordinates to (4, 5)
processing:  (4, 5) 30 1 3
setting coordinates to (1, 2)

Yet another approach would be to place your setup code for each parameter in separate functions and use a recursive function to implement the nesting of parameter variations.  This would not require any data structures to control the execution as everything would be defined by the order of parameters given to the nesting function.
def nest(process,data,setup,*more):
    for value in data:
        setup(value)
        if more:
            nest(process,*more)
        else:
            process()

Usage:
coordinates = [(1,2),(2,3),(4,5)]
powers      = [10,20,30]
delays      = [1,1.5,2]
pulses      = [3,5,7]

def setupCoord(xy):
    # call your coordinate functions here
    print("setting coordinates to",xy)

def setupPower(power):
    # call your coordinate functions here
    print("setting power to",power)

def setupDelay(delay):
    # call your delay functions here
    print("setting delay to",delay)

def setupPulse(pulse):
    # call your pulse functions here
    print("setting pulse to",pulse)

def testInstrument():
    print("Testing instrument ...")
    
nest(testInstrument,
     coordinates, setupCoord,   # zip(x_coords, y_coords), setupCoord,
     powers,      setupPower,   # params['power_list'],    setupPower,
     delays,      setupDelay,   # params['delay_list'],    setupDelay,
     pulses,      setupPulse)   # params['pulse_list'],    setupPulse)

output:
setting coordinates to (1, 2)
setting power to 10
setting delay to 1
setting pulse to 3
Testing instrument ...
setting pulse to 5
Testing instrument ...
setting pulse to 7
Testing instrument ...
setting delay to 1.5
setting pulse to 3
Testing instrument ...
setting pulse to 5
Testing instrument ...
setting pulse to 7
Testing instrument ...

Note that, for this solution, you cannot use an actual iterator (e.g. zip) for data at the second and lower levels of nesting.  It must be converted to a list so that it can restart un subsequent iterations of higher levels.  itertools.product internally compensates for this (possibly by storing lower nesting levels somewhere) so it doesn't have that issue.
Also note that the nest() function merely streamlines the code.  If you're not comfortable with recursion, you could do the same thing with a comprehension:
iCombo = (_ for _ in map(setupCoord,coordinates)
            for _ in map(setupPower,powers)
            for _ in map(setupDelay,delays)
            for _ in map(setupPulse,pulses) )
for _ in iCombo:
    testInstrument()


One could start with the idea of an effectual iterator: one that invokes a user-defined effect each time its __next__ method is called:
class EffectualIterable:
    def __init__(self, itr, effect):
        self.iterable = itr
        self.effect = effect
        self._cache = None

    # Clumsy attempt to handle arbitrary iterables;
    # probably a better way to handle this.
    def __iter__(self):
        if self._cache is None:
            self._cache = []
            for x in self.iterable:
                self.effect(x)
                self._cache.append(x)
                yield x
        else:
            yield from map(self.effect, self._cache)

Note that EffectualIterable.__iter__ is a generator function, so a new iterator is created each time it is called.
Each of your original iterables gets wrapped as an effectual iterable, which will call the appropriate state transformer for your instrument.
def update_position(x):
    instr.move_axes(*x)
    do_something_else_x_y()

def update_power(x):
    instr.set_power(x)
    do_something_else_power()

def update_delay(x):
    instr.set_delay(x)
    do_something_else_delay()

def update_pulse(x):
    instr.set_pulse(x)
    do_something_else_pulse()

position = EffectualIterable(zip(x_coords, y_coords), update_position)
power = EffectualIterable(params['power_list'], update_power)
delay = EffectualIterable(params['delay_list'], update_delay)
pulse = EffectualIterable(params['pulse_list'], update_pulse)

Next, we need an effectual product, which will actually iterate over its iterables multiple times. (itertools.product pre-traveres each of its arguments once to cache the items it will yield.) For simplicity, I don't implement an arbitrary n-way product, just a specialized 4-way product.
class EffectualProduct:
    def __init__(self, i1, i2, i3, i4):
        self.iters = [i1, i2, i3, i4]

    def __iter__(self):
        for x1 in self.iters[0]:
            for x2 in self.iters[1]:
                for x3 in self.iters[2]:
                    for x4 in self.iters[3]:
                        yield x1, x2, x3, x4

Now, you can modify your loop simply by rearranging the arguments to EffectualProduct (and updating the tuple unpacking):
for t, p, d, pl in EffectualProduct(position, power, delay, pulse):
    x, y = t
    do_something_else()


As written, the nested iterators will be exhausted upon hitting the second item of their parent loop ?  This would not yield a "product" of values.  You would end up with one combination for each of the x4 values containing the first item of x1, x2 and x3. Every other iteration of the higher level loops would find nothing in their nested loops on exhausted iterators.

No, EffectualIterable.__iter__ is a generator function, so each nested loop creates a fresh iterator.

I see, this works because only the first level is an actual iterator (zip) and others are lists.  If position had been placed last in the call to EffectualProduct, then the issue I was describing would occur.

Oh, OK, I see what you mean. Give me moment to fix this.

Hmm.. maybe it's just simpler to require EffectualIterable to take an iterable, like list(zip(...)), instead of trying to cache an arbitrary iterator on the fly...

Thanks for this solution @chepner. Is it possible to have an arbitrary number of nested loops ?

No. That's where you either need recursion (which can handle a large, but not arbitrary, number of iterables) or a more complicated algorithm that doesn't explicitly iterate over each iterable. (See Modules/itertoolsmodule.c in the CPython source code, in the product_next function, which maintains the last tuple returned and which indices should be updated in the next result.)

You can always define EffectualProduct2, EffectualProduct3, etc for how ever many fixed iterables you want to compute a product for. There is a limit to how many nested loops you can have, but it's relatively large (I want to say 255, but don't quote me on that.)
